Выборка из каталога файлов, в имени которых строго только цифры
glob.glob(patch+'*.*')

Так получаю список всех файлов с любым расширением.
Возможно ли задать таким образом, чтобы получить список всех файлов, в имени которых исключительно цифры, не зависимо от расширения?

Ну, банальный os.listdir? Зачем тут glob вообще

Только самому фильтровать результат простейшей регуляркой.

glob по мне куда практичней. Разве в ней нельзя сразу регулярку прописать на выборку файлов, имена которых строго цифры, без букв и каких других символов.

Судя по тому, что пишут на английском СО - нельзя. Операционные системы регулярки не поддерживают при получении списка файлов/каталогов, значит вы ничего всё-равно не сэкономите, если бы там и были встроенные регулярки, это бы делалось выше уровня ОС, список файлов всё-равно целиком бы читался и только потом обрабатывался.

Ну а вообще в виде однострочника [x for x in os.listdir(patch) if os.path.splitext(x)[0].isdigit()] или [x for x in pathlib.Path(patch).iterdir() if x.stem.isdigit()]

from pathlib import Path

def list_numeric_files(directory):
    # Создаем объект Path для указанной директории
    path = Path(directory)
    # Ищем все файлы в директории
    files =path.glob('*')
    # Фильтруем файлы, имена которых состоят только из цифр
    return [file for file in files if file.is_file() and file.stem.isdigit()]



# Домашняя директория
directory = Path.home()
numeric_files = list_numeric_files(directory)

for file in numeric_files:
    print(file)


C:\Users\user\111.txt


Решение через filter - применяем re.search на список файлов из glob.glob:
import glob
import re

def glob_re(pattern, strings):
    return list(filter(re.compile(pattern).search, strings))

pattern = r'(?<=\/)[0-9]+\.[^.]+$'
glob_list = glob.glob(r'/var/www/user/data/*.*')

filenames = glob_re(pattern, glob_list)

Linux: (?<=\/)[0-9]+\.[^.]+$
Windows: (?<=\\)[0-9]+\.[^.]+$
Решение работает именно со списком файловых путей, а не с названиями файлов, так как (?<=\/) или (?<=\\) ищет разделитель путей.
На выходе получаем отфильтрованный список с исходными полными путями до файлов:
print(glob_list)  # Все файловые пути
print(filenames)  # Отфильтрованные файлы

['/var/www/user/data/1241351.py', '/var/www/user/data/test1.py', '/var/www/user/data/12431241.txt', '/var/www/user/data/123test.txt']
['/var/www/user/data/1241351.py', '/var/www/user/data/12431241.txt']


Что та у меня не работает glob.glob('*.*') возвращает массив всех файлов, а вот list(glob_re(r'^[\d]*\.', glob.glob('*.*'))) , пустой массив

Может это связанно с операционной системой или ошибка в выражении? glob.glob('*.*') возвращает файл с полным путем от корня. Может в этом дело?

Даже не знаю, указываю полный путь до папки к примеру '/var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/.' Быть может в этом дело?

Есть предположение, что могут возвращаться не имена файлов по типу file.txt, а полные пути, которые и не пройдут выражение

Да, так оно и есть. Список фалов с полными путями от корня, возвращает glob.glob('*.*') возможна регулярка под это?

@Алекс обновил код и выражение на работу со списком файловых путей (просто названий файлов будет недостаточно). По итогу фильтрации пути остаются неизменными.
